# published ms visual studio 2012 not working

Tags: visual-studio-2012, publishing, fileshare, vshost32

I've created a C# project and wanted to publish it. As working in MS Visual studio 2012, I followed the 'How to publish : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/31kztyey.aspx '.
So i selected all the right folders on my file share device, and it build well.
But after i installed the project through the setup.exe, i try to run the .appliction but it doenst show me the form i created, while in taskmanager the process with the description 'Vshost32.exe' can't be killed, if i say 'end process' it reappears, but still doenst show me my project.

I ran the project (before publishing) in both debug mode and release mode. I tried to publish via cd-rom instead of file-share, but same problem appeared.

How can i publish my poject now for other company members without MS Visual Studio on our file share device, so they can also run it ? ( i don't think, simply copying the .exe out of the bin\release folder is a clean way to do it)